# Casting function block

Tags: plc, codesys, wago, pfc200

I'm using Wago PFC200 for my home automation. I got base function block:

`FUNCTION_BLOCK ABSTRACT Room`

and two the interface:

```
INTERFACE IBlinds
- BlindsUp
- BlindsDown
```

and

```
ILights
-TurnOffLights
-TurnOnLights
```

My room's instances looks like this:

`FUNCTION_BLOCK Garage EXTENDS Room IMPLEMENTS ILights, IBlinds`

In my PLC_PRG I've all instances of my rooms:

```
PROGRAM PLC_PRG
VAR
    Bedroom: Bedroom;
    Garage: Garage; 
    Hall: Hall;
    Boilerroom: Boilerroom;
    ...
END_VAR
```

Under the PLC_PRG I've some methods to e.g.: automate blids:

```
METHOD MoveBlindsToMorningPosition
VAR CONSTANT
    siCount: SINT := 5;
END_VAR
VAR_INPUT
    xMoveSignal: BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR
    _siIndex: SINT;
    _rooms: ARRAY[0..siCount] OF POINTER TO IBlinds := [ADR(Livingroom), ADR(Diningroom), ADR(Kitchen), ADR(Toilet), ADR(Boilerroom), ADR(Garage)];
END_VAR

FOR _siIndex := 0 TO siCount DO
    _rooms[_siIndex]^.MoveBlindsToMorningPosition(xMove := xMoveSignal);
END_FOR
```

But I got the following compilation errors in the _rooms array: `C0032: Cannot convert type 'POINTER TO Garage' to type 'POINTER TO IBlinds'`

My function blocks actually implement IBlinds. Is there a way to cast function block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, an `interface` is already a `reference` to a function block:

> CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of an interface as references.

So there shouldn't be a need to use `pointers`.

Secondly, to cast an function block into an interface, personally I'd recommend using a dedicated method inside a function block. For example:

```
INTERFACE inter1
- ...
- ToInter1
```

```
INTERFACE inter2
- ...
- ToInter2
```

and implement them inside MyObject like:

```
ToInter1 := THIS^;
```

```
ToInter2 := THIS^;
```

And then you can:

```
myObj: MyObject;
i1: inter1 := myObj.ToInter1();
i2: inter2 := myObj.ToInter2();
```

Or

```
arr: ARRAY[x..y] OF inter1;
arr[z] := myObj.ToInter1();
```

At least this is what I do to solve this

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that CODESYS always treats variables declared with the type of interface as references.

Comment: Was in your shooes a while ago. The [codesys documentation](https://help.codesys.com/webapp/_cds_obj_interface;product=codesys;version=3.5.16.0) is your friend is such times ;)

Comment: I'm programming for 15 years but I'm just starting with the PLC programming :) I'm automating my home using PFC200. Do you have some experience with OSCAT Building ligrary?

Comment: I think I found one more option - usage of `__QUERYINTERFACE`. https://help.codesys.com/webapp/_cds_operator_queryinterface;product=codesys;version=3.5.16.0

Comment: Unfortunatly no, I have no expirience with OSCAT Building, as I work in the industrial water plant automation. Also, we have looked at OSCAT basic, but in the end decided to write our own libraries for anything we need. As for `__QUERYINTERFACE` it does `"type conversion of an interface reference into another type"`, I don't think this iswhat you were looking for. And unless you have hundreeds of interfaces, imo having a dedicated method for conversion is easier to read and debug.